# is there a solution for the integration of $x^n(x+c)^k$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Is there a solution to this integration without using bionomial theorem to expand the power of the terms in the brackets? 
$$\int x^n(x+c)^kdx$$
where $n$, $c$, and $k$ are constants. $c$ is a real number and $n$, $k$ are positive real numbers.

Comment: Are $n$ and $k$ positive integers?

Comment: @OscarLanzi The're positive but not necessary integers

Comment: There goes my idea then, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a solution which involves the gaussian hypergeometric function
$$I=\int x^n(x+c)^k\,dx=\frac{x^{n+1} (c+x)^{k+1}}{(n+1)c} \, _2F_1\left(1,k+n+2;n+2;-\frac{x}{c}\right)$$

You can write it using $x= ct$ and use the binomial expansion
$$I=\int x^n(x+c)^k\,dx=c^{k+n+1}\int t^n(t+1)^k  \,dt=c^{k+n+1}\int t^n \sum_{p=0}^\infty\binom{k}{p}t^p\,dt $$
$$I=c^{k+n+1}\sum_{p=0}^\infty \int\binom{k}{p}t^{p+n}\,dt=c^{k+n+1}\sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{\binom{k}{p}}{n+p+1}t^{n+p+1}$$

Comment: Nice trick. I think the sum is $\sum_{p=0}^k$ right?

Comment: oops! $k$ and $n$ are not necessary integers...

Comment: @AymenKareem The formula still holds for non-integer $n,k$. Binomial coefficients and exponentiation can be defined for (almost) all numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $x\mapsto-ct$ to get

$$\int_0^ax^n(x+c)^k~\mathrm dx=(-1)^nc^{n+k+1}\int_0^{-a/c}t^n(1-t)^k~\mathrm dt=(-1)^nc^{n+k+1}\mathrm B(-a/c;n+1,k+1)$$

where $\rm B$ is the [incomplete beta function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function).

In the particular case that $-a/c=1$, this reduces to the Beta function. If $n$ is an integer, then by substituting $x\mapsto t-c$, we can get a closed form by binomially expanding. If $k$ is an integer, we can directly binomially expand. Alternatively, one may use integration by parts. If $n+k$ is an integer, this can be solved with $t/(t-1)\mapsto u$.

As $a\to\infty$, the substitution $t/(t-1)\mapsto u$ also gives us

$$\int_0^\infty x^n(x+c)^k~\mathrm dx=c^{n+k+1}\mathrm B(n+1,-(n+k+1))$$

when it converges.

Comment: I think the second term needs edit. the bracket raised to k not multiplied

Comment: What happens if $a \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Typo fixed. As $a\to\infty$ we get some more special cases, if it converges.

Comment: Can you explain what is $t$ and $u$? Also in the second term you have $dt$???

Comment: That was a typo. $x=-ct$ so $t=-x/c$, and $t/(t-1)=u$ so $t=u/(u-1)$.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. However, I still didn't get how you come to your final equation when $a\rightarrow \infty$. This is what's important to me

Comment: See the linked Wikipedia for identities, or simply perform the provided substitution.

Comment: Do you mean I plug $t=u/(u-1)$ into $\int_0^{-a/c}t^n(1-t)^kdt$ and solve the integration?

Comment: Yes, that is the substitution used.